# Spring Boot / Spring Data import.sql doesn't run Spring-Boot-1.0.0.RC1

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-boot

I've been following the development of Spring Boot, and sometime between the initial version `0.0.5-BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and the current version I am using `1.0.0.RC1` I am no longer running my `import.sql` script.

Here is my configuration for `LocalContainerEntityManager` and `JpaVendorAdapter`

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("foo.*");
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }
```

Interesting the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` still seems to run, which I think is part of the definition of my `SpringBootServletInitializer`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

However, I also noticed that the tables generated no longer have *underscores* and changed their shape when generated?

However, that could be the result of updating my `org.postgresql` version like so:

Previously:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.2-1004-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

Now:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

I also had to change `pggetserialsequence` to `pg_get_serial_sequence` to get the script to run at all from `pgadmin`?

I guess I'm confusing what's going on, but most importantly I want to get back to having my `import.sql` run.

I have been following the sample project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa

And their `import.sql` isn't running either on `1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `import.sql` script is a Hibernate feature I think (not Spring or Spring Boot). It must be running in the sample otherwise the tests would fail, but in any case it only runs if ddl-auto is set to create the tables.  With Spring Boot you should ensure that `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is set to "create" or "create-drop" (the latter is the default in Boot for an embedded database, but not for others, e.g. postgres).

If you want to unconditionally run a SQL script, By default Spring Boot will run one independent of Hibernate settings if you put it in `classpath:schema.sql` (or `classpath:schema-<platform>.sql` where `<platform>` is "postgres" in your case).

I think you can probably delete the `JpaVendorAdapter` and also the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` (unless you are using `persistence.xml`) and let Boot take control. The packages to scan can be set using an `@EntityScan` annotation (new in Spring Boot).

The default table naming scheme was changed in Boot 1.0.0.RC1 (so nothing to do with your postgres dependency). I'm not sure that will still be the case in RC2, but anyway you can go back to the old Hibernate defaults by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy`.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I see all your contributions to the project! And I really appreciate you taking the time to point out this out to me.

Comment: ... and if `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`, then `import.sql` will not run.

Answer (score 4):

Hey I came across similar issue. My sql script was not getting invoked initially. Then I tried renaming the file from "import.sql" to "**schema.sql**", it worked. May be give this a shot. My code can be found here - https://github.com/sidnan/spring-batch-example

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was already said, it's worth noting you can use the **data.sql** file to import/intialize data into your tables. Just put your data.sql into the root of the classpath (eg: if you're running a Spring Boot app, you put it in the **src/main/resources** path).

Like was said before, use it together with the property **ddl-auto=create-drop**, so that it won't crash trying to insert the existing data.

You can also set up which specific file to execute using the **spring.datasource.data** property. Check out more info here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Note: the schema.sql mentioned before would contain the whole DB definition. If you want to use this, ensure that Hibernate doesn't try to construct the DB for you based on the Java Entities from your project. This is what de doc says:

> If you want to use the schema.sql initialization in a JPA app (with
>   Hibernate) then ddl-auto=create-drop will lead to errors if Hibernate
>   tries to create the same tables. To avoid those errors set ddl-auto
>   explicitly to "" (preferable) or "none"