# Spring boot fails to load DataSource using PostgreSQL driver

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, spring-boot

I have successfully developed a prototype using Spring Boot 1.0.2.RELEASE (was 1.0.1.RELEASE until today).

I have searched and searched and tried solutions like:
[Spring Boot jdbc datasource autoconfiguration fails on standalone tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854585/spring-boot-jdbc-datasource-autoconfiguration-fails-on-standalone-tomcat)
[Spring Boot / Spring Data import.sql doesn't run Spring-Boot-1.0.0.RC1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422664/spring-boot-spring-data-import-sql-doesnt-run-spring-boot-1-0-0-rc1)

They all suggests to let Spring Boot do the job.
When using H2, everything works, but when I try to switch to PostgreSQL, i get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined
```

My build.gradle is as follow:

```
loadConfiguration()

def loadConfiguration() {
def environment = hasProperty('env') ? env : 'dev'
project.ext.envrionment = environment
println "Environment is set to $environment"

def configFile = file('config.groovy')
def config = new ConfigSlurper("$environment").parse(configFile.toURL())
project.ext.config = config
}

buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.0.2.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-   plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

war {
baseName = 'test'
version =  '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

configurations {
providedRuntime
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${springBootVersion}")

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:${springBootVersion}")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
compile("postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4")
//compile("com.h2database:h2")

testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/cms
spring.datasource.username=cms
spring.datasource.password=NA
```

Removing application.properties and changing the dependency back to H2 and everything is OK.

I can't find where I am doing wrong :-(

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Where did this come from: `database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver`? Don't you mean `spring.datasource.driverClassName`?

Comment: Absolutely. Copy-n-paste typo! Question updated. Thanks!

Comment: WHAT A TYPO MISTAKE! Ok, datasource and not database *sigh*

Answer (score 17):

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Make sure to reload your project if you recently just added postgres to your dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

some time try re-import your mvn project if dependencies are not refreshed , also add following to your `pom.xml`

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

Or to your `build.gradle`

```
implementation "postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4"
```

Comment: he has a gradle project!

Comment: You can try this site to convert maven to gradle
https://sagioto.github.io/maven2gradle/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, that required me to check my pom.xml and I had left the H2 dep in, replacing it with

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Seems to have fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `build.gradle`:

> implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:*version-number*'

but, no matter what i did, the jar was never downloaded.

As a work-around, i downloaded the jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.14)(Clicked on `Jar(...)`), and added it in my **Java Build Path - Libraries** manually.
Not ideal, but that's the only thing that works in 2 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

I just came over this thread but it doesent helped me,
for me the problem was also in a false configured pom.xml,
I just had to add JPA:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue when our project migrated to Java 17 and gradle 7.5

below steps I have followed to resolve the issue.

gradle import upgraded to : `implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.27'`

then clean build the project: `./gradlew clean build`
then `./gradlew bootRun`

solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here while looking for plain JDBC solution:

Use `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDatabase?currentSchema=mySchema`

The following works when using Hibernate as JPA provider:
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=mySchema`